# What the failure "Operation is not supported for read-only collection" in Android Studio is about?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Yesterday I updated the Android Studio to the latest one:

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708, built on November 9, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.1.2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    Statistic (4.2.7)
    com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.1(231)-23)
```

and now I am not able to tun any project I could run in the previous version. Here is the failure: `Operation is not supported for read-only collection`

Just for making sure I also created a test project with the latest versions of:

- Gradle: 8.5
- Android Gradle Plugin Version: 8.2.0
- [Jetbrains Kotlin Android](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin): 1.9.20
- [Kotlin Compiler Extension Version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose): 1.5.5

It does not look to me that there is a compatibility issue. Otherwise the old projects would get compiled. No project can be compiled and all of them show the same result:

[image]

What might be the problem? Incidentally, I already reported the issue from the Android Studio to Google, but not sure if they will take a look in.

Comment: Facing the same issue after updating. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @kaigalmane not yet, I can't work, all my projects have been stepped due to this issue.

Comment: I just restored Android Studio to default settings and it's working fine now.

Comment: Dude, that worked well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Restore default did not work for me, I need to delete folder from AppData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @kaigalmane there is a solution that helped us to solve the issue. Just restore default settings of IDE: `File` -> `Manage IDE Settings` -> `Restore Default Settings...`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I updated Android Studio, and I was able to resolve it by unchecking this option in settings :

```
Settings > Experimental > Trace Gradle Import with profile
```

If that doesn't work, try to uncheck other experimental options.

Comment: This might also be exaclty the one that gets unchecked after restoring default setting.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I just restored Android Studio to default settings and it's working fine now.  This is the solution to This Error and it's simple and easy.

Answer (score -1):

I was originally facing the same problem that I could not receive SHA-1 and SHA-256. I did all the steps, but in Griddle 8.2.1, my problem was not solved again.

So I accidentally decided after setting the default griddle settings manually. I turned some options off and on, which solved my problem. If you have a problem, try it. If it doesn't work, do the default settings.

[image: my settings]

Comment: Which part of that solved the problem? Also, are you able to explain why (you think) that solved the issue?

Comment: I was facing the same problem that I could not receive SHA-1 and SHA-256. I did all the steps, but in Griddle 8.2.1, my problem was not solved again, so I accidentally decided after setting the default griddle settings manually. I turned some options off and on, which solved my problem. If you have a problem, try it. If it doesn't work, do the default settings.